# Python 3.6 How do you efficiently compare 2 unordered lists of strings, preserve duplicates, and resolve for unequal list sizes?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, list, duplicates, comparison

In my case, I have two lists of varying lengths. The first requires at least one entry of each in the second for success, duplicates included must be matched entry for entry. For instance:

`['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'duplicate']` and `['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'no', 'duplicate']` would return `False`

and

`['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'duplicate']` and `['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'possible', 'duplicate']` would return `True`

I have tried with sets, but that doesn't preserve duplicates. I have also tried to use `for in` loops to pass through it, but they have proven too slow for the number of comparisons needing to be completed at runtime.

There must be a more efficient way to do this. Who can help me?

------------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------

This was originally asked with the intention of finding the most efficient way of solving the [Ransom Note](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem) challenge on HackerRank.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake similar, but not an exact match. I'm not looking at how many manipulations are required to match, I'm looking for whether or not a suitable amount of each necessary element is available in the second list. Edit Distance suggests arriving at sameness while the issue only requires a list of inclusion. Thanks for affording me the opportunity to reread that bit, though.

Comment: Tested your code with the sample data, the second one returns False

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer, from piecing together other things I've been looking at (somewhere around 20 different answers to similar questions missing critical pieces and needing to be put together).

The `Counter` from `collections` seems to be the way to go about this, using the `-` comparator and checking for an empty dict in the result. A contrived situation that illustrates is the interview question of "How do you tell if a magazine (list) contains every word you wish to have in a ransom note (list)?"

The most efficient answer I can think of, and piece together, as mentioned above is:

```
from collections import Counter

def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    return (Counter(ransom) - Counter(magazine)) == {}
```

If anyone has something more efficient, please let me know.

Thanks,

Spiznak

Comment: That isn't an empty set, that is an empty *dict*.

Comment: This doesn't preserve the order either

Comment: Also, the difference won't be the empty set if the second list has additional words

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I'm not interested in preserving order, only verifying that sufficient values exist in the second list. And the dict will be empty as this Counter only subtracts what exists in the second list from the first and returns what is left of the first.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, updated with the correction. My first thought was an empty object (coming from a JavaScript-heavy contract), but I believe that would be closer to a map? I could be wrong, though as I'm still quite new to Python.

Comment: @Spiznak Don't you want to preserve the order in the *first* list? Also, I stand by what I said about the difference not being empty (case in point: your second example). As for your last question: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a subclass of `dict` which is fairly close to a JS object (although it doesn't serve double-duty as the 'object' type in Python).

Comment: I've tested this code with your sample input. Neither pair results in an empty `Counter`.

Comment: If you want to check if it's empty, use `len(...) == 0`

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding why you'd accept an answer that doesn't behave the way that you yourself have described in your question. And it has a bug in it to boot. Especially since these things have been pointed out to you beforehand. Perhaps I am mistaken or perhaps you didn't describe the problem accurately. In either case, the least you could do is to respond.

Comment: It was originally asked with the intention of finding the most efficient way of solving the [Ransom Note](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem) challenge on HackerRank. Compare our answers there, if you have an account...

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your question correctly, all you need to do is loop over the first list, checking whether the corresponding entry in the second list matches, and making sure to skip any words in the second list that do not match. If you manage to exhaust the first list this way, you know the lists match by your criteria.

If your previous solution was too slow, I imagine it's because you were using a slower algorithm. It's hard to tell, since you haven't described the sample space in any way (if it's massive, you might need to dip into a low-level language, or use specialised libraries like `numpy`).

---

This is not the prettiest implementation one could imagine, but I'll leave it here for now, until I have time to polish it. Apologies for the sloppy naming and poor style.

```
first =  ['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'duplicate'], ['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'no', 'duplicate']
second = ['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'duplicate'], ['I', 'have', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'a', 'possible', 'duplicate']

# TODO: Come up with Haskell solution
# TODO: Parallelise
# TODO: Suggest numpy solution
def match(a, b):
  c = iter(b)

  # Loop over the first list
  for word in a:
    try:
      # Checking whether there's a matching entry in the other list,
      # making sure to skip past non-matches
      while  word != next(c):
        pass
    except StopIteration:
      # We've run out of entries in the second list,
      # before exhausting the first one.
      return False
  else:
    # We've matched all entries in the first list
    return True
  return False

assert not match(first[0], first[1])
assert match(second[0], second[1])
```

Comment: Samples should be `100 < n <= 300` perceptibly. Your solution is closer to O(n^2) at worst with O(n^2)/2 on average as it loops through the longer of the 2 lists, which may not contain a sufficient amount of duplicate entries in the first without a catch for that. This is similar to what I started with.

Comment: @Spiznak, I actually don't think it's O(n^2), since you're not restarting the inner loop each time. It will only check any entry *once* at most.

Comment: @Spiznak Since one requirement is that every word in list 1 is also in list 2, the function will simple return false if it exhausts all words in list 2 without finding a match. Unless I've misunderstood your question, I don't believe I need a separate check for that.

Comment: To be precise, it *would* be O(n*m) rather than O(n^2) if the inner loop was repeated in full for every iteration of the outer loop. But that's not the case (this is why I used `c = iter(b)` rather than looping over `b` directly).

Comment: @Spiznak You are however right that you could add checks that short-circuit the entire loop in some cases.

Comment: In a side-by-side comparison, mine had a more consistent and successful performance. I tried with data sets as large as 30k (to see the differences) and found the Counter solution to be more accurate and faster. I do appreciate your efforts, though.

Comment: @Spiznak Interesting. It's still not O(n^2) though, unless I've missed something. Would you mind showing me the data so I can work out where the bottleneck is?